What I should add as a key to LaunchedEffect to be changeable?
So, I need to run some code inside a LaunchedEffect.
First I wanted to use a Boolean, but once I set it to true, the LaunchedEffect block wasn't triggered again. I tried to set the value to null, before I set it to true again, but it didn't work as well.
Now I simple set it to Int type, and if I increase the value by 1 every time, it works as expected.
I used like this:
    val boolState = remember {
        mutableStateOf<Boolean?>(null)
    }
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = boolState.value) {
        if(boolState.value == true){
            //Do something
        }
    }

So my question is, what should I use as a key, to be able to update any time?

I dont't know your exact use case, but if you need a variable just to trigger a LaunchedEffect, this indicates a design problem. Especially if you don't even need a CoroutineScope at all. Maybe you can execute the code from your LaunchedEffect at the same place in your code where you modify the boolState variable?

In Jetpack Compose, the LaunchedEffect will only trigger when the key changes. If you want to trigger the effect every time regardless of the key, you need a strategy to ensure the key changes whenever you want the effect to re-run.
Your approach with an Int works because the value changes every time, thus triggering the effect. However, if you prefer using a Boolean or need more control over when the LaunchedEffect triggers, do something like this:
boolState.value = !boolState.value`val boolState = remember { 
   mutableStateOf(false)
}    
LaunchedEffect(key1 = boolState.value) {
        if (boolState.value) {
            // Do something
       }
}`


Thanks, actually I don't need a coroutine. I'm just right now trying a similar solution, I have a UIState, and I set the bool to false, every time when I press the button, after that I validate the data, if it has error, I update the bool to true. I just thought the LaunchedEffect is more like a compose related solution.

Then you must try this Instead... You can use a DisposableEffect which is more suitable for such cases where you don't necessarily need coroutines.
val boolState = remember { mutableStateOf<Boolean?>(null) }
DisposableEffect(key1 = boolState.value) {
if (boolState.value == true) {
// Do something
}
onDispose {
    // Cleanup if necessary
}

}
With DisposableEffect, you get the same key parameter functionality and a clean-up mechanism via the onDispose block if needed. This way, you avoid using coroutines directly.

Surprisingly, my original implementation works, with a little adjustment.
So I wasn't so detailed in my question, because I was sure, that the bool causing the problem, but not.
I develop my project in MVI, so I have a UI state which is a StateFlow, which contains the bool param.
I wanted to update it (with .update() fun) by set it to false and back to true, but I think this update was missed, or optimized, because it didn't trigger recomposition.
Basically I just changed the logic, and I set to false in the LauncedEffect block, and updated it to true, after a button press.
I also tested my original solution, and I added some delay in the validation fun, so basically, between the two update call, there was a 10 sec delay, and it worked well
